# Error: ECONNREFUSED when making a POST request to an API

Tags: node.js, docker, express, asp.net-core, passport.js

I have this system composed of a SPA, an Express.js Server, and an ASP NET Core MVC API.

My server uses Passport.js in order to use OAuth with external Providers, so that way I can offer SSO options in my SPA, besides the login form. The way this works is, after obtaining the User Info from the Provider it sends this data, via a POST request, to the API in order to authenticate the user. If the user chooses to use the login form instead of one of the SSO options, it makes the POST request directly to the API with the User's email and password.

So far, working locally I've had no issues with it. I was requested to containerize the system, so I created a Dockerfile for each of these components, a docker-compose.yml to aggregate them, ran docker-compose build and docker-compose up with no issues.

Now, running the containers, I can use my SPA with no issues if I choose the log in via the form, but if I try to use SSO, I get an ECONNREFUSED error when making the POST request to the API, which is weird since my SPA Services make HTTP requests to the same Address with no issues.

```
webportal.client_1      | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8443
webportal.client_1      |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1142:16) {
webportal.client_1      |   errno: -111,
webportal.client_1      |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
webportal.client_1      |   syscall: 'connect',
webportal.client_1      |   address: '127.0.0.1',
webportal.client_1      |   port: 8443,
webportal.client_1      |   response: undefined
webportal.client_1      | }
```

Here is my Server.ts

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { initialiseAuthentication } from "./auth";
import path from "path";
import http from "http";

require("dotenv").config({
  path: __dirname + `/./../.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../build")));

app.use(session({ secret: "The big secret" }));

app.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: "Pong" });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());

initialiseAuthentication(app);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
```

My Api.ts where the Server makes the HTTP Requests

```
import request from "superagent";

async function verifyUser(
  email: string,
  name: string,
  provider: string,
  providerId: string
) {
  return await request
    .post(`${process.env.BACKEND_API_URL}/authentication/externalAuth`)
    .send({
      Email: email,
      Name: name,
      Provider: provider,
      ProviderId: providerId,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

async function getUserById(data) {
  return await request
    .get(`${process.env.BACKEND_API_URL}/user/${data.Id}`)
    .auth(data, { type: "bearer" })
    .then((res) => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

export { verifyUser, getUserById };
```

My AuthenticationService.ts in the SPA

```
import request from "superagent";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export async function SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
  return request
    .post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL}/authentication/internalAuth`
    )
    .send({ username: email, password: password });
}

export async function GetUserInfo(userId: number) {
  const jwt = Cookies.get("jwt");
  return request
    .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL}/user`)
    .query({ id: userId })
    .auth(jwt as string, { type: "bearer" })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.body;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone would be able to clarify this issue for me and possibly solve it. Thank you.

**Edit 1:** The requests are all in HTTPS and yes, I have CORS enabled allowing everything.

**Edit 2:** Added Docker-Compose and Dockerfiles.

Docker-Compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "VeryStrongPassword1234"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

  migrations:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: migrations.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db

  api:
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8443:443"
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=VeryStrongPassword123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes: 
      - ../certs/:/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - migrations

  spa_server:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    build: 
      context: ../client
      dockerfile: client.Dockerfile
```

Migrations Dockerfile

```
#Get base SDK Image from Microsft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build-env
WORKDIR /app

#Restore any dependecies
COPY ./Migrations ./Migrations
COPY ./Main/appsettings.json ./.Main/appsettings.json
COPY ./Main/appsettings.Development.json ./Main/appsettings.Development.json
COPY ./Roles.Persistence ./Roles.Persistence
COPY ./Users.Persistence ./Users.Persistence
RUN dotnet restore ./Migrations/Migrations.csproj

#Build our release
RUN dotnet publish ./Migrations/Migrations.csproj -c Release --no-restore

#Generate runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/Migrations/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","Migrations.dll"]
```

API Dockerfile

```
#Get base SDK Image from Microsft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build-env
WORKDIR /app

#Restore any dependecies
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore ./Main/Main.csproj

#Build our release
RUN dotnet publish ./Main/Main.csproj -c Release --no-restore

#Generate runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 443
COPY --from=build-env /app/Main/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","Main.dll"]
```

SPA and Server Dockerfile

```
# Get base image from Node
FROM node:latest as build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Restore dependencies
COPY . ./
RUN npm i -g env-cmd
RUN npm i -g npm-run-all
RUN yarn

# Build client
RUN yarn build:container

# Generate image
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start:container"]
```

Comment: Can you provide docker-compose file?

Comment: Yes, I just added it with the Dockerfiles.

Comment: you haven't exposed the port locally as 8443.

Comment: You should link server to your api.
and instead of 127.0.0.1:8443 you shoud use name of container api:8443

Comment: Expose by adding it to the EXPOSE in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

What was wrong was the port I was using.
In order for the SPA to make requests, from the browser, I need to use the external port, which is 8443. So the Server, which is running in the container needs to call the internal port, 443, and now it is working as intended.

Thank you all.

Comment: Thank you; I'd forgotten this. I had my container pointing to the service name of the API container but using it's 'exposed' port. Switching to point to the internal port yielded immediate success.